# Monitoring Telegram Channel joins and leaves by bot

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

How can I access to a Telegram channel Member joins and leave notifications with a bot registered as channel admin?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using Telegram Bot API (Technically not possible as of 03 Feb 2016). Bots (if set as admins) can only post to channels and nothing else.

However, you may try to write your LUA script to [Telegram-CLI Bot](https://github.com/yagop/telegram-bot) (which emulates normal user, making it behave like bot)